# How to introduce an interval scale for items of sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let suppose we have the set: $A=\{D, d, e, r, R\}$, whose elements divides the set of real numbers on the intervals:
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
   D, & x \in (-\infty, -E]\\
   d, &  x \in (-E, 0)\\
   e, &  x = 0 \\
   r, &  x \in (0, E]\\
   R, &  x \in (E, \infty)\\
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $E$ is a threshold. Then we use the function  $f(x) \in \{D, d, e, r, R\}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ in next algorithm.

**Algorithm.**

Step 1. Generate values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$, $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $i = 1,2,\ldots,k$.

Step 2. Make an item by concatenation $k-1$ times the realisation of function $f(x)$:

$$f(x_1) \& f(x_2) \& \ldots \& f(x_k).$$

Step 3. We repeat $n$ times steps 1-2  and as result we have the sequence of items:
$$F = \{f(x_1) \& f(x_2) \& \ldots \& f(x_k), f(x_1) \& f(x_2) \& \ldots \& f(x_k), \ldots, f(x_1) \& f(x_2) \& \ldots \& f(x_k)\}. $$

For example, for $k=4$ we have sequence of items: $$F=\{(Dere), (errR), (RdeR), \ldots , (ddDD)\},$$ $|F| = n <\infty$.

I need to measure the degree of difference between items from $F$.

**Question.** Is it possible to introduce an interval scale for items?

**My idea is:** a) to compare items and define the nominal scale,
b)  to sort items alphabetically and define the ordinal scale.

**Edit.**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681573/how-can-i-find-the-record-from-a-data-set-that-is-most-similar-to-a-test-record) is very interesting solution for integers.

Comment: Which role does your $f$ function have in the question?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, i have added some details for the function 'f'.

Comment: I don't understand. In step 1 you have selected elements of $A$ directly. Where do the $x_i$s in step 2 come from?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, you are right, I re-write the step 1.